# Client Disconnect with message "Peer Created" - PUN

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, photon

I am developing multiplayer game in unity using **Photon Unity Network** plugin.
At present, I have completed half of my game. Today I am facing new issue regarding connection of client.

Initially it connects with room but after sometime it automatically disconnected from server and this is happening for every client that was exist in room.

```
GUILayout.Label(PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString());
```

Above statement display **Peer Created** message on screen and after that

```
 void OnConnectionFail()
{
    Debug.Log("OnConnectionFail");
}
```

method gets called.

So what to do in this situation? Because data of this client was lost suddenly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting answer of this question based on experience related to **PUN**.
It works for me also.

First I have download latest version of **PUN** from [Photon Unity Networking Free](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/1786).
One problem also found after communicating with Photon team that they are updating their server by the time. So  we can't able to connect with that server.

From my side, I have problem in **DNS** setting. I sent my project to my friend and it works nicely on his system. So I can able to find their is something wrong with my system.

I hope this suggestion become helpful to other members also. As of my personal experience, working with photon server has great experience for me.